# Horizontal UitableView with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am implementing a horizontal UITableView for showing some Sticker category . Here is my code for rotation of Table View.

```
- (void)refreshOrientation
{
    if (!self.tableView)
        return;

    // First reset rotation
    self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    // Adjust frame
    int xOrigin = (self.bounds.size.width - self.bounds.size.height) / 2.0;
    int yOrigin = (self.bounds.size.height - self.bounds.size.width) / 2.0;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width);

    // Apply rotation again
    self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height - 7.0);
}
```

And Rotation of Table View Cell Contents

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.delegate tableView:self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Rotate if needed
    if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(cell.contentView.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity))
    {
        int xOrigin = (cell.bounds.size.width - cell.bounds.size.height) / 2.0;
        int yOrigin = (cell.bounds.size.height - cell.bounds.size.width) / 2.0;
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, cell.bounds.size.height, cell.bounds.size.width);
        cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Its working fine without auto layout. but if i use auto layout constraints it got Crooked . Thanks in advance if anyone can help me understand the rotation concept in auto layout .

Comment: A better option is to use UICollectionView instead of implementing a horizontal UITableView using rotation transform..

Comment: say for some limitations i have to use a UITableView . there must be some way to do this with auto layout .